# How to format result of array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to format this result of array:

```
[{"name":"Pendapatan","y":"1464333560100.00"}]
```

in to this format:

```
[{name:'Pendapatan',y:1464333560100.00}]
```

i have try str replace but the result remove all string

```
[{name:Pendapatan,y:1464333560100.00}]
```

what should i do?

Comment: you need to use json_encode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Why do you want this particular format? It's not JSON.

Comment: this is result from json_encode n i must change the format

Comment: And why would you change from double to single quotes ? I don't see the point here...

Comment: i want use this result into var n call it in javascript... just call with result where i want..

Comment: Then use what `json_encode` gives you! It's already valid Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that would remotely make sense would be to change `"1464333560100.00"` to `1464333560100`, i.e. change the string to a number. That's a valid change. To do that, you need to make your PHP value a number, not a string:

```
json_encode(['y' => '1464333560100.00'])  →  string
json_encode(['y' => 1464333560100.00])    →  number
```

Do note that the result will be `1464333560100`, without trailing `.00`. That's because those two numbers are equivalent; it's irrelevant how many trailing zeros you have, it doesn't change the value as such.

The rest of the formatting change is completely irrelevant. Whether you have single quotes or double quotes or no quotes does not change the data structure and its values at all. If your goal is to produce valid JSON, then the format as is (double quotes everywhere) is in fact necessary.

Comment: yes u right..but the point here ..i want remove all quote..but only leave quote where the value type is string in this case "pendapatan" '(only that value where have quote and remove the remaining)

Comment: Why do you insist on that? What's wrong with having quoted keys? If this is just a personal preference (because there's no technical reason for it), then you'll have to write your own not-quite-a-JSON-encoder.

Comment: there is nothing wrong at all ... This result comes from php json_encode, I want to save it to a variable, then I just need to call these variables in javascript function ex <script> Results: <? echo myvar ; ?> </ Script>

Comment: Then just go ahead and do that. No need to futz around with the format at all.

Answer (score 0):

I got it wrong. You can use this;

```
json_encode(array('name' => 'Pendapatan', 'y' => 1464333560100.00));
```

Also you can do the test for json on this site http://jsoneditoronline.org/